# adb stops working after running sshuttle

Tags: adb, ubuntu-16.04, macos-sierra

I recently bought a MacBook and migrated to macOS from Ubuntu. The surprise happens when I run sshuttle and begin ssh-tunneling in my mac. In Ubuntu, my adb continues to work perfectly but it's in macOS that adb stops working with the error `error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was due to sshuttle. sshuttle automatically forwarded also localhost requests so the connection to adb was lost.
I cloned the repo and went back to `ef83a5c` and built the program again. [this bug](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/159) was found approximately two weeks ago [partially fixed once](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/pull/162) and now it's again under development.

```
git clone https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle.git
git checkout ef83a5c
sudo ./setup.py install
```